# how to do typecast inside django query filter?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a query like this:

```
uids = Message.objects.filter(content_type_id = offer_ct_id).values_list('content_uid', flat=True) 

offer_uids = Offer.objects.filter(uid__in=uids).values_list('uid', flat=True)
```

where uids is a list of UUIDs

```
[UUID('e7571ea3-b5b7-48e5-b015-1f03133f2b0c'), UUID('e4e7f0c9-c68d-462e-8bcd-0ae69e43d11f')] and
```

and uid in Offer model is Character field.
So when I'm using the above query, got an error

> ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: `character = uuid
>   LINE 1: ...CT U0."uid" FROM "offers_offer" U0 WHERE U0."uid" IN (SELECT...`

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think the argument to `.filter(uid__in=)` needs to be a list of strings rather than a list of UUIDs

Comment: What is the end result you're trying to get? is it the same as `queryset.filter(..).offer_set`?

Comment: My intention is to get  messages of all offers. Offer and Message is a generic relation.

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your models..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  offer_uids = Offer.objects.filter(uid__in=[ str(uid) for uid in uids]).values_list('uid', flat=True)
```

Comment: Its works I know, But there are more than 100K UUIDs in the list and time consuming

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: is this running on an offline script or on your webserver?

Comment: its not possible to send UUID in django filtering queryset. if it was offline script, then i would recommend to do it parallel  (open threads). but its not recommended to open thread like this if this action is on your webserver. if its only an admin action, then its ok that if a user waits.. but if still its an issue, then you must change the code that return you this list of UUIDs, you need to convert it to str there..

Comment: Its a Message model and is growing day by day. So converting into str using list comprehension is not a convenient way. This will surely cause issues in future

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this also by overriding the model manager of Offer.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets

The override method should check of the value type and if it is UUID or a list of UUID you should cast them to string.

Note that, if value is a list, it will not enhance the performance of the query. This is just another way to do it.

**Update:**
So I'll assume that your offer model is like the following

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField("Offer UUID", max_length=150)
    # here what you should add to override manager
    objects = OfferManager()
```

Your Manager then should be as follows

```
class OfferManager(models.Manager):
    def filterby_uuid(self, uuid):
        return models.query.QuerySet(self.model).filter(uuid = str(uuid) )
    def filterby_uuid_list(self, uuid_list):
        return models.query.QuerySet(self.model).filter(uuid__in =[ str(uuid) for uuid in uuid_list] )
```

Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
Offer.objects.filterby_uuid_list(uids).values_list('uid', flat=True)
```

This is a general idea of how can overriding Manager solve the problem in another way rather than repeating the same filter again and again.